# Find extra rows from data table merge in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a CSV file containing a list of 9541 pairs of point IDs and distances between them, and another file containing the same pairs but a different distance for each.  I'm 99% sure they're the same pairs.

I've put them in tables `a` and `b`, and merge them like this:

```
names(a) <- c('Point1', 'Point2', 'Distance')
names(b) <- c('Point1', 'Point2', 'Cheby')
m <- merge(a, b)
```

All good, except `m` has 8 extra rows than I was expecting.  I've tried merging with `all.x=TRUE` and `all.y=TRUE` as well, with the same results, and no fields are `NA`.  How do I find what the 8 extra rows are so I can figure out why they're there?

I've tried merging `m` back with `a` and `b` to see what rows have `NA`, but there aren't any.  Even weirder, there are now 9565 rows.  If I merge a small subset of the data frames, it works perfectly, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way of finding out what's going wrong than merging increasingly large subsets until I get an unexpected number of rows back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like some of the points might be duplicated within a data frame? Try

```
a1 <- a[,-ncol(a)]
a1[duplicated(a1),]
b1 <- b[,-ncol(b)]
b1[duplicated(b1),]
```

to see if there are any duplicate points.

**Edit:** Also, to get all the rows in `a` that have duplicated points, you can do this:

```
a1 <- a[,-ncol(a)]
duplicated_points_a <- a1[duplicated(a1),]
merge(duplicated_points_a, a)
```

Comment: Ah, you're spot on, thanks.  BTW, `b1[duplicated(b1),]` shows the 4 duplicates: is there an easy way to show all 8 points, i.e. the duplicates and the points that they are duplicates of?  (if they had different distances in `b`)

Comment: I've added a few lines of code - is this what you need?